# Apollo Websocket repeatedly attempts to connect over and over when updating context

Tags: go, websocket, apollo, apollo-client, gqlgen

I'm using Apollo on my frontend to manage queries and GQLgen on the backend to handle resolvers.

I've noticed this only occurs if `webSocketInit` returns a new ctx value. If I return the original ctx, everything works as expected.

//main.go

```
    srv.AddTransport(&transport.Websocket{
        Upgrader: websocket.Upgrader{
            ReadBufferSize:  2048,
            WriteBufferSize: 2048,
            // Resolve cross-domain problems
            CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
                return true
            },
        },
        InitFunc: func(ctx context.Context, initPayload transport.InitPayload) (context.Context, error) {
            return webSocketInit(ctx, initPayload)
        },
        KeepAlivePingInterval: 10 * time.Second,
    })
```

```
func webSocketInit(ctx context.Context, initPayload transport.InitPayload) (context.Context, error) {
    //Process auth token 
    ctxNew := context.WithValue(ctx, "token", token)
    return ctxNew, nil
}
```

//client.tsx

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = subscribeToMore({
            document: MY_SUBSCRIPTION_GQL,
            updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }: any) => {
                //...process new data

                return Object.assign({}, prev, {
                    data: newData,
                });
            },
            onError: (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            },
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
```

//apolloclient

```
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    const token = store.getState().user.token;
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        },
    };
});

const wsLink =
    typeof window !== 'undefined'
        ? new GraphQLWsLink(
              createClient({
                  url: 'ws://localhost:8080',
                  lazy: true,
                  connectionParams: () => ({
                      Authorization: store.getState().user.token,
                  }),

                  on: {
                      connected: () => {
                          console.log('connected');
                      },
                      error: (e) => {
                          console.log(e);
                      },
                  },
              })
          )
        : null;

// HTTP Requests
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: `http://localhost:8080/`,
});

const link =
    typeof window !== 'undefined' && wsLink != null
        ? split(
              ({ query }) => {
                  const def = getMainDefinition(query);
                  return def.kind === 'OperationDefinition' && def.operation === 'subscription';
              },
              wsLink,
              authLink.concat(httpLink)
          )
        : authLink.concat(httpLink);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false,
    }),
});
```